# hive table to view the avro records which is streamed using flume getting Block size invalid or too large for this implementation: -40

Tags: twitter, hive, flume, hive-serde

I am creating the hive serde external table to view the twitter records which is streaming using flume.

My property file

```
# Naming the components on the current agent. 
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter 
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel 
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

# Describing/Configuring the source 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = kafka

# Describing/Configuring the sink 

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://xxx:8000/topics/flumedata
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 100000 
TwitterAgent.sinks.hdfs.serializer=Text

# Describing/Configuring the channel
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory 
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 100000 
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.byteCapacity = 6912212

# Binding the source and sink to the channel 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
```

Query to create a hive external table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE twitter_tweets
  COMMENT "just drop the schema right into the HQL"
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
  TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.literal'='{
       "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Doc",
  "doc" : "adoc",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "user_friends_count",
    "type" : [ "int", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "user_location",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "user_description",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "user_statuses_count",
    "type" : [ "int", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "user_followers_count",
    "type" : [ "int", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "user_name",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "user_screen_name",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "created_at",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "text",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "retweet_count",
    "type" : [ "long", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "retweeted",
    "type" : [ "boolean", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "in_reply_to_user_id",
    "type" : [ "long", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "source",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "in_reply_to_status_id",
    "type" : [ "long", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "media_url_https",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "expanded_url",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  } ]
}');


LOAD DATA INPATH '/topics/flumedata/FlumeData.*' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE twitter_tweets;
```

After creating the table, when i hit select * from twitter_tweets;
It is not giving any data, it throughs an error

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.io.IOException: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Block size invalid or too large for this implementation: -40
```

Where i went wrong, i dono why iam getting this block size issue. Can anyone guide me.

Comment: @ Rakesh Gupta did you face this above issue?

Comment: @Farrukhmuneer can you please help me